# Electron shows blank window

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

My HTML file isn't loading at the tutorial says it would've. This is what I have. Yes, I've tried doing all sorts of funky stuff involving paths and it doesn't fix the issue.

`main.js`

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require("path");

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    })
  
    win.loadFile("index.html")
  }

  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
  })
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Photo of project directory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to change your JavaScript code to have a full path to the HTML file.

---

Try with the code below, it will configure Electron. In the event listening, it is creating a new `BrowserWindow` with no configuration (although you can add it if you like). Then, it is loading the full path to the HTML file.

```js
const electron = require("electron");

const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow
} = electron;

app.on("ready", () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}\\index.html`);
});
```

Comment: That works, but why?

Comment: It's most likely the way Electron works. It likes to have the full path, not the relative path.